# Remove duplicates from inside arrays in an object javascript

Tags: arrays, duplicates, javascript-objects

I have an array of objects... (actually I'm not sure what I have but it looks like this)

```
list = 

{
"ZIG": [
    "CSK",
    "DKR",
    "CSK",
    "YNA",
    "CSK"
],
"ZKG": [
    "YNA"
],
"ZND": [
    "NIM",
    "DKR",
    "AJY"
],
"ZNE": [
    "PHE",
    "PER"
]
}
```

And I'm looking for a way to end up with

```
list = 

{
"ZIG": [
    "DKR",
    "YNA",
    "CSK"
],
"ZKG": [
    "YNA"
],
"ZND": [
    "NIM",
    "DKR",
    "AJY"
],
"ZNE": [
    "PHE",
    "PER"
]
}
```

I was able to remove most of the duplicates by using `uniq` but there are still some duplicates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With **ES6** you can do something like this:

```js
const list = { "ZIG": [ "CSK", "DKR", "CSK", "YNA", "CSK" ], "ZKG": [ "YNA" ], "ZND": [ "NIM", "DKR", "AJY" ], "ZNE": [ "PHE", "PER" ] }

const r = Object.entries(list).map(([k,v]) => ({[k]: Array.from(new Set(v))}))

console.log(...r)
```

Where you would get the entries of the object (via [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)) [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) each of it and then compose the new values via using new [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set). Lastly just [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) the resulting array to get the desired object result.